# How to grep the exact match and print only that match

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I have file's will lot's of data , need to print the exact keyword in following format : `Filename : Keyword : line number`

*[Note : need to search recursively the entire directory for a keyword]*

For example : I want to search **keyword :** `abcxyz`

**Data in file is like below**

```
abcxyz.fgh

gfhj.abcxyz

i have a book with name abcxyz.sh

where is my brother called : abcxyz.fsdghj raju how are you 

afsgdjj kllf

ghjakl  ra jksu ldlahlalfb  afhkflkaf dbllf jll  afl;bnhafl
```

When i am using this following command : `grep "abcxyz" *.*` it's printing entire line that i don't need

**Expected Output :**

```
Filename : abcxyz.fgh    : line number 
Filename : gfhj.abcxyz   : line number
Filename : abcxyz.sh     : line number
Filename : abcxyz.fsdghj : line number
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be a job for `awk`, could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`. Please mention absolute path in place of `.` to get run it for any directory in find command.

The output should be `filename : matched string(s) : line number` for all files.

You could run following `find` command:

```
find . -type f -exec awk -f script.awk {} +
```

Where `script.awk` is as follows:

```
cat script.awk
BEGIN{ OFS=" : " }
NF{
  val=""
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i~/abcxyz/){
      val=(val?val OFS:"")$i
    }
  }
  if(val){
    print FILENAME,val,FNR
  }
}
```

For your shown samples(considering empty lines in it), sample output will be as follows.

```
Input_file  :  abcxyz.fgh     :  1
Input_file  :  gfhj.abcxyz    :  3
Input_file  :  abcxyz.sh      :  5
Input_file  :  abcxyz.fsdghj  :  7
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
BEGIN{ OFS=" : " }              ##Setting OFS to space colon space in BEGIN section of this program.
NF{                             ##Checking condition if line is NOT empty then do following.
  val=""
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){           ##Traversing through all field values here.
    if($i~/abcxyz/){            ##checking condition if field is matching abcxyz then do following.
      val=(val?val OFS:"")$i    ##Creating val which has value of current field and keep adding it.
    }
  }
  if(val){                      ##Checking condition if val is NOT NULL then do following.
    print FILENAME,val,FNR      ##Printing FILENAME val and FNR here.
  }
}
'
```

Answer (score 4):

Here you go

`grep -roHn "\S*Your_text_here\S*" *`

tags

-r : recursively in the directory

-o : only the matched part

-H : with file name

-n : with line number

then tweaked the regex to include every characters except space, tabs and newline around your matched pattern using `\S` .
Note : If you just want alphabets and numbers and no special symbols use `\w` instead.

and then the final '*' to indicate to search every file and folder in your current directory. So to use this command first `cd` to the required directory.

Comment: Funny, you interpreted the question the opposite way of how I did. I can understand that. One of our answer will probably turn out to be not what OP wants. I was completely sure of my reading. But probably so were you. Let's see.

Comment: Looks like you read it correctly. Have fun.

Comment: Why do you use `*` as path, instead of `.` for the simple "here"?

Comment: I used `*` of habit. I usually require to choose files with specific format like '*.txt'.   `.`  totally works for this case.

Comment: The order of the output data and formatting was important requirement to codeholic24. That part of the question was not covered by me too. Maybe I will edit my answer later on if someone else doesn't.  For now let's keep it simple :)

Comment: You should use `\S` instead of `\w` as the OP wants to match more than just word-constituent chars, e.g. `.`, see the expected output. You should also mention this requires GNU grep.

Comment: Yes, you are right Ed. I failed to observe the `.` as requirement . /S is a much better fit.